# While i hovering over images they are little bit dangling?

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
     #rightbar a:hover img
    {
      border:1px solid #5cadff;
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    #rightbar  img
   {  
     padding:20px 58px; 
     }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rightbar">
                <h3>MultiMedia</h3><br/>
                <a href="#"><img src="exercises-for-fitness-in-pregnancy.jpg" alt="youtube video"></a> <br/>
                <a href="#"><img src="exercises-for-fitness-in-pregnancy.jpg" alt="youtube video"></a> <br/>
                <a href="#"><img src="exercises-for-fitness-in-pregnancy.jpg" alt="youtube video"></a> <br/>
                <a href="#"><img src="exercises-for-fitness-in-pregnancy.jpg" alt="youtube video"></a> <br/>

        </div>
```

I do not want the images to dangle when i hover over it?
How to get rid of it and i want images to be still when i hovero over.

Comment: any working Fiddle available ?

Comment: try to this rightbar a img{border:solid 1px transparent;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be caused of the border. Try this:

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
     #rightbar img:hover
    {
      border:1px solid #5cadff;
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    #rightbar img
   {  
     border:1px solid transparent;
     padding:20px 58px; 
     }

    </style>
```

Comment: completely right... but i would suggest to add a transparent color to the border as we don't know on which background this will be displayed.

Comment: yeah, forgot about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your visual dangle is caused by the border added on hover which adds 1px around the image. you can solve that by adding `border:1px solid transparent` to the `#rightbar  img`

This will solve you issue

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the border at the time of hover, so flickering happens. try replace with this..

```
 #rightbar img
   {  
     padding:20px 58px; 
     border:1px solid transparent;
   }
```

and here is the [**FIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/5abnscud/1/)

Answer (score 0):

When you set a 1 px border, it shifts 1px to right to make space for the border. So you can decrease margin-left by 1px in hover action.

```
 #rightbar a:hover img{
  border:1px solid #5cadff;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```